# How to get the rightest match by regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I think this is a common problem. But I didn't find a satisfactory answer elsewhere.

Suppose I extract some links from a website. The links are like the following:

```
http://example.com/goto/http://example1.com/123.html
http://example1.com/456.html
http://example.com/yyy/goto/http://example2.com/789.html
http://example3.com/xxx.html
```

I want to use regular expression to convert them to their real links:

```
http://example1.com/123.html
http://example1.com/456.html
http://example2.com/789.html
http://example3.com/xxx.html
```

However, I can't do that because of the greedy feature of RE.
`'http://.*$'` will only match the whole sentence. Then I tried `'http://.*?$'` but it didn't work either. Nor did `re.findall`. So is there any other way to do this?

---

Yes. I can do it by `str.split` or `str.index`. But I'm still curious about whether there is a RE solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regex you can use `str.split()` to split your links with `//` then pickup the last part and concatenate that with `http//`:

```
>>> s="""http://example.com/goto/http://example1.com/123.html
... http://example1.com/456.html
... http://example.com/yyy/goto/http://example2.com/789.html
... http://example3.com/xxx.html"""
>>> ['http://'+s.split('//')[-1] for link in s.split('\n')]
['http://example3.com/xxx.html', 'http://example3.com/xxx.html', 'http://example3.com/xxx.html', 'http://example3.com/xxx.html']
```

And with regex you just need to replace all characters between 2 `//` with empty string but as you need one of `//` for the first use a [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
>>> [re.sub(r'(?<=//)(.*)//','',link) for link in s.split('\n')]
['http://example1.com/123.html', 'http://example1.com/456.html', 'http://example2.com/789.html', 'http://example3.com/xxx.html']
>>>
```

Comment: Well, I know I can do it by some string manipulations. But I still want a one step RE solution.

Comment: @user2923419 OK, i add another way with regex!;) but still the first way be recommended!

Comment: @Kasra Thanks. I didn't think about using sub. But sub is quite useful here because it will return unmatched string.

Comment: I found another solution without using sub: `re.match('(?:http://.*)?(http://.+)$',original_link).group(1)`

Comment: @user2923419 glad to hear about that! so what about accepting my answer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

<s>use this pattern</s>

```
^(.*?[^/])(?=\/[^/]).*?([^/]+)$
```

and replace with `$1/$2`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/220)

---

after reading comment below, use this pattern to capture what you want

```
(http://(?:[^h]|h(?!ttp:))*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/221)

---

or this pattern

```
(http://(?:(?!http:).)*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/222)

---

or this pattern

```
http://.*?(?=http://)
```

and replace with nothing
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/223)

Comment: @JanneKarila, I misunderstood the request, updated answer above